# Rails - Routes for Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a conversations controller and a comments controller.

What I would like to do is have the following (from the logs):

```
Started POST "/conversations/217/comment_beta" for 127.0.0.1
```

Post the Comments Controller not the Conversations Controller which is what Rails is trying to do now:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'comment_beta' could not be found for ConversationsController):
```

Here is my routes file:

```
  resources :conversations do
    resources :comments, :only => [:create, :update,:destroy, :comment_beta], :constraint => {:context_type => "conversations"} do
      collection do
        post 'comment_beta'
      end
    end
    collection do
      get 'read_updater'
    end
  end
```

Suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your rails routes is actually doing what it is supposed to do. if you conversations/:id/comment_beta to go to your comments controller, either you should change your routes via `match` or go to the correct url which is /conversations/:id/comments/:comment_id/comment_beta

If you're posting to create a new comment, why aren't you using RESTful routes?

```
resources :conversations do
  resources :comments do
    collection do
      post 'comment_beta'
    end
  end
end
```

should give you /conversations/:id/comments/comment_beta

collection because you don't need an id

Comment: @corroded Thanks for the reply. I like your second option, but how would that be in the routes file?

Comment: Wait... I'm posting a NEW comment to create a comment. I don't have a comment_id

Comment: if you're posting a new comment why aren't you using RESTful routes? (ill change y answer to show you)

Comment: I'm using RESTful now for create comment, problem is I'm building a beta version of my app which has a different controller behavior so I'm trying to create a temporary CREATE for comment.

Comment: i see, lemme change it up again

Comment: Same Error: "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/conversations/217/comment_beta"):" I'll update the question with the latest routes file

Comment: @Corroded the question has been updated with the routes file per your suggestion. Thoughts?

Comment: you're accessing the wrong route. look at my answer, you need to go to comoments/comment_beta if you want the thing to post to your comments controller

Comment: Thanks but my update is exactly what you have? What am I missing? sorry

Comment: My mistake, I was POSTIng the wrong URL. thanks for your help!